# Optimize MySQL UPDATE query that contains WHERE and ORDER BY?

Tags: mysql, indexing, query-optimization

How can I optimize this query?  If I run it without the ORDER BY clause, it executes in <100ms.  With the ORDER BY clause it takes many seconds, and crushes the server when more than one system is trying to make this query at once.

```
UPDATE companies
SET
    crawling = 1
WHERE
    crawling = 0
    AND url_host IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    last_crawled ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

If I run this query as a SELECT, it's also fast ( <100ms ).

```
SELECT id
FROM companies
WHERE
    crawling = 0
    AND url_host IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY
    last_crawled ASC
LIMIT 1;
```

Here is my table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `companies` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url_scheme` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `url_host` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `crawl` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `crawling` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `last_crawled` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `name` (`name`),
  KEY `url_host` (`url_host`),
  KEY `crawl` (`crawl`),
  KEY `crawling` (`crawling`),
  KEY `last_crawled` (`last_crawled`),
  KEY `url_scheme` (`url_scheme`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

---

**UPDATE ONE**

This query gives me the following error: `You can't specify target table 'companies' for update in FROM clause`

```
UPDATE companies
SET crawling = 1
WHERE id = (
    SELECT id
    FROM companies
    WHERE
        crawling = 0
        AND url_host IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY
        last_crawled ASC
    LIMIT 1
);
```

This query gives me the following error: `This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'`

```
UPDATE companies
SET crawling = 1
WHERE id in (
    SELECT id
    FROM companies
    WHERE
        crawling = 0
        AND url_host IS NOT NULL
    ORDER BY
        last_crawled ASC
    LIMIT 1
);
```

Comment: What's the execution plans look like for w/ the order and w/o the order?  Looks like an index on last_Crawled may be missing.

Comment: Have you an index on last_crawled? Seeing as the select is fast just grab the id and use that in the update, is the obvious work around though

Comment: @xQbert & @Tony Hopkinson - There is an index on `last_crawled`. There are no compound indexes, though.  Maybe one is needed.

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson - I'm using this query to select the next company to crawl, so I can't separate the SELECT and the UPDATE queries or else other processes requesting the next company will overlap.

Comment: @T.BrianJones That's why I wanted to see the execution plans to find out if a full table scan was being used on the order by or if an index was being hit :P

Comment: @xQbert - I'm not sure what you mean by "execution plan."  Happy to provide more details if you can clarify.

Comment: in SQL an execution plan shows how the database engine generates the results.  It shows what indexes are used, or not used and can be viewed to determine where sub-optimal SQL may exist.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html shows an example or http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: I'd be seriously and urgently looking at a crawling table and delegate the management and scheduling to something other than the table you have it on.

Comment: @Tony Hopkinson - Could you point me to some resources that discuss this sort of crawling / process management and different ways of handling it.  The way I'm currently managing everything does not feel correct ... which is usually a sign that there's a much better solution.

Comment: It's not difficult. A table or some other resource to hold sites that you want to crawl next or are crawling, which means you can forget all your indexing problems. And then some other task to 'choose the next site(s) to crawl. You can have the next site task ticking away happily in the background and it's performance will be a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

try not to use ORDER-BY and LIMIT for such small number of updates.

```
    UPDATE companies t1
    join
    (
        SELECT c.id,@RowNum:=@RowNum+1 AS RowID
        FROM companies c, (SELECT @RowNum := 0)r
        WHERE c.crawling = 0 AND c.url_host IS NOT NULL
        ORDER BY c.last_crawled ASC
    )t2
    ON t2.RowID=1 AND t1.id=t2.id
    SET t1.crawling = 1
```

EDIT:1

**make sure you have the index on (last_crawled ASC , id ASC)**

```
    UPDATE companies t1
    join
    (
        Select ID,RowID
        From
        (
            SELECT c.id,@RowNum:=@RowNum+1 AS RowID
            FROM companies c, (SELECT @RowNum := 0)r
            WHERE c.crawling = 0 AND c.url_host IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY c.last_crawled ASC
        )t2
        WHERE ROWID=1
    )t3
    ON t1.id=t3.id
    SET t1.crawling = 1
```

Comment: This works, but is much slower ( >30s ). The companies table has millions of rows if that makes a difference.  I'm not familiar with some of the syntax you are using in this query ( eg. `@RowNum:=@RowNum+1` ), so I, unfortunately, can't make any other educated comments on it.

Comment: in the sub-query i am assigning the rownumber and then selecting only top 1. try the updated query.

Comment: even if you have index, performance is highly depends on the cardinality of the column crawling. it seems like possile values are 0 and 1 so you can imagine that column is not the best choice to perform update on the table using that column in where condition. but if we do not have anything else i guess this best we can do.